# JPA spring does not respect FetchType.LAZY

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I tried to increate the performance of my SpringBoot app with MariaDB. 
I logged the sql and analyze it and figure it out that the FetchType.LAZY is not respected.

I have a MainEntity class

```
@MappedSuperclass
@DynamicUpdate
open class MainEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "BIGINT UNSIGNED")
    var id: Long = 0

    var createdAt: Timestamp? = null
    var updatedAt: Timestamp? = null

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    var createdBy: UserStaff? = null

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    var updatedBy: UserStaff? = null

    @PrePersist
    fun prePersist() {
        val loggedInUser = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication?.credentials
        if(loggedInUser is UserStaff) {
            createdBy = createdBy ?: loggedInUser
        }
    }

    @PreUpdate
    fun preUpdate() {
        updatedAt = Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())
        val loggedInUser = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication?.credentials
        if(loggedInUser is UserStaff) {
            updatedBy = loggedInUser
        }
    }

}
```

where UserStaff entity:

```
@Entity
class UserStaff : MainEntity(), UserDetails {

    var fullName: String? = null

    @Column(name = "username")
    var uname: String? = null

    @Column(name = "password")
    var pwd: String? = null

    ..... more details
}
```

and then I have another Entity that inherit MainEntity

```
@Entity
class CashMutation: MainEntity() {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    var from: Office? = null

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    var to: Office? = null

    @Column(columnDefinition = "DECIMAL(20,5)")
    var value: BigDecimal? = null

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    var approvedBy: UserStaff? = null

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    var sendBy: UserStaff? = null

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    var status: MutationStatus? = null

    var remark: String? = null
}

@Repository
interface CashMutationKasRepository : JpaRepository<CashMutation, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<CashMutation> {
    fun findAllByStatusIdNot(id: Long) : List<CashMutation>
}
```

Then I have a RestController

```
@GetMapping("/test/20")
    fun test20() {
        mutationRepository.findAll().forEach {
            println(it.id)
        }
    }
```

When I look at the sql log, it also query the `createdBy` of the `CashMutation` and then also querty the `createdBy` of the `UserStaff` until it is null. It also queries the Office including the `createdBy` inside Office (since all my entities inherit `MainEntity`)

I looked around and found some similar problems but their solution does not work for me (for example, set `spring.jpa.open-in-view=false` in my properties). I tried to use `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` but it also dies not work.

Thank you and cheers!

Comment: Found a potential solution. It is back to basic that I did not read the proper tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-kotlin/ `In order to make lazy fetching working as expected, entities should be open as described in KT-28525. We are going to use the Kotlin allopen plugin for that purpose.`

Comment: As mentioned the classes should be `open` (as hibernate uses proxies) and second make sure you aren't using `data classes` from Kotlin!. The latter generates a `toString` including all fields (so your `println` would lead to initialization after all because it would be needed to write the `String` to the console.